# Exact definition of: if ($variable) { ... } in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, null, isset

What's the exact definition of this construct in PHP ?

```
if ($variable) {
   ...
}
```

What is checked here: variable set ? variable not null ? variable not empty ? variable true / not false ? The official docs make it very hard to find information on that, plus there are a lot of misleading comments in those docs.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Everything else would be considered true, and thus trigger the statement.

Answer (score 3):

An `if` condition always boils down to a boolean comparison. Whatever expression you provide as the condition, it will always have to boil down to either `true` or `false`. `if ($variable)` evaluates whether the variable (loosely) equals `true` or `false`. Have a look at the [type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to see what values count as what.